# Problemas con caracteres especiales en Highcharts y json

Tags: html, json, python-2.7, highcharts, utf-8

Tengo un archivo `datos.json` que contiene datos en español con acentos y otros caracteres especiales. Al utilizarlo en un gráfico Highcharts, me despliega los acentos y eñes con signos de interrogación.

Demás está decir que el archivo .html contiene un `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`, que la codificación de todos los archivos estan en `UTF-8` , que existe la etiqueta `<html lang="es">`,  que probé cambiando la extensión a PHP e incorporando un `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` al inicio del archivo, que probé incorporando un `<script charset="UTF-8">` en el script del gráfico.  Incluso cambie el `$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {}`, [que se usa originalmente](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#3) en este gráfico, por un `$.ajax({})` para poder configurar el `scriptCharset` y el `contentType` con `UTF-8` pero nada siempre el mismo resultado. Tampoco pude utilizar un `unescape(encodeURIComponent(data))` o `decodeURIComponent(escape(data))` ya que no me despliega el gráfico.

---

**Archivo datos.json:**

```
[["Perro", 55], ["Niño", 34], ["papá", 31], ["mamá", 26], ["gato", 18]]
```

---

**Script del gráfico (reducido para el ejemplo):**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

     var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{}]
};

    $.ajax({
        url: "datos.json",
        scriptCharset: "utf-8",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            options.series[0].data = data;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

---

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización:**
El archivo json lo genera un script Python guardandolo de la siguiente forma:

```
#Cuenta las 10 palabras más repetidas de una colección llamada filteredtext
counter = collections.Counter(filteredtext).most_common(10)

#Genera un archivo  json con los datos de counter 
#Utilizo 'ensure_ascii=False' para que imprima los acentos y eñes.
counterJson = json.dumps(counter, ensure_ascii=False)

#Guarda los datos en un archivo plano de extención.json
json = open('datos.json',"w")
json.write(counterJson)
json.close()
```

Comment: Revisé en este [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bs4cjLkd/) y en el tooltip de la gráfica no vi problemas con los caracteres especiales; si es posible, te pido crear un ejemplo funcional usando jsfiddle para que así otros usuarios también puedan intentar resolver esta novedad.

Comment: Mauricio, gracias por tu comentario. En tu ejemplo no hay acentos pero y de todas formas si agrego los datos en el mismo archivo no hay problema, el problema se da con un json que se encuentra aparte.

Comment: Eduardo, lo siento si no me expliqué bien, debiste agregar los datos en el jsfiddle que dejé en mi comentario _(lo cual hiciste)_. Ahora dices: `el problema se da con un json que se encuentra aparte.`, te recomiendo elaborar una respuesta para ayudar a posibles usuarios que tengan un problema similar. Saludos.

Comment: No parece que sea cosa de Highcharts, probando ejemplos en codepen se ven los acentos y eñes sin problema. ¿Puede ser que el navegador que usas tenga otra codificación?¿o el servidor donde tienes la página?

Comment: Blonfu, al parecer no es de Highcharts porque en otros caso me retorna los acentos de forma correcta. Esta es la única vez que he tenido un problema por lo que descarto lo del navegador y servidor. Descartando varias cosas es posible que sea la transferencia del archivo .json en bruto al gráfico. Cuando hago he referenciado un json.php, con datos generados con PHP tampoco hay problema por que lo codifico en UTF-8, este json lo genera un script python y es posible que ahí este el problema.

Comment: Cuando recibes el json e imprimes options.series[0].data = data; como llegan esos caracteres??

Comment: @sioesi: Incluí un alert(data) antes de options.series[0].data = data y ya llegan mal.

Comment: Como haces tu consulta en la BD?

Comment: No hay consulta, un script python  extrae información masiva de la web , la procesa y genera un archivo json con datos

Comment: Guarde dos archivos .json igual a lo que dejas de ejemplo 1 en UTF-8 y otro en ISO 8859-1, con el segundo me ocurre el mismo problema, VERIFICASTE que tu archivo.json se guarda correctamente?

Comment: @sioesi, actualicé la pregunta con el procedimiento para guardar el json

Comment: @EduardoMunizaga agrega `.encode('utf8')` a dumps

Comment: @sioesi , lo hice y nada. :-(

Comment: Efectivamente se trataba de un problema al guardar el archivo json en python. Lo codifica en ANSI por omisión.  Lo solucioné de una forma rudimentaria, convirtiendo el archivo de ANSI a UTF-8. ¿Actualizo la pregunta o la contesto yo mismo?

Comment: @EduardoMunizaga deberías responder a tu propia pregunta. Y por cierto, que bueno que hayas encontrado la solución :).

Comment: Pudo solucionar el tema? tengo el mismo inconveniente, pero no se como solucionarlo. Gracias.

Comment: por que no parseas el codigo en python text.encode("la famosa ñ").decode("utf-8") y luego lo envias